# Open Source GoToAssist Alternative

Tags: remote-access

We're trying to trim our budget and one of the items that I believe we can trim is our GoToAssist account. Granted it is not that expensive but I have to think there is a lot of open source RA software out there. Of course I am aware of VNC but I was wondering if there are any more sophisticated open source offerings that offer a proxy-based connection (ie no firewall configuration/exceptions) like GoToAssist does. I am referring to a Windows environment fyi.

Comment: Are you looking for actual open source, or just "free"?

Comment: I'd prefer open source, but I'll take what I can get

Comment: think there are vnc based version that will do the same thing as gotoassist, also win7 has remote assist that works with most firewalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [BigBlueButton](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/) as well.

Open source software; your server; your control

Answer (score 2):

I love and use logmein and they have a [free offering](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/).  However, it's not open source...

Comment: I LOVE LogMeIn, but unfortunately using it in a corporate environment is a violation of the TOS.

Comment: Logmein also offers Join.me for simple GoToAssist type sessions and it's free - http://join.me

Comment: @DKNUCKLES - LogMeIn is free to use in a corporate environment:  http://community.logmein.com/t5/Free/LMI-Free-for-commercial-use/td-p/41320

Comment: I stand corrected! My apologies - I could have sworn I read somewhere that it was only free for a personal setting and not for a corporate environment.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Echogent's Echoware here: http://www.echogent.com/tech.htm

Pieces of it are free and open source (the client stuff which is what I think you want), other parts are try-before-you-buy.

Comment: That seems to not exist anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) or [ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/)